# various questions about setTimeout using backbone.js. Clean and resume timeouts

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have various questions about setTimeout:
- In my code, I clean timeouts with `clearTimeout(content.idTimeout)`  for a particular idTiemout, but how clear all timeouts?
I have the next model:

```
var ContentModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
URL: "http://localhost/example.php",    
requestType: "POST",
dataType: "json",
data: "", //Set the value outside the model
idTimeout: "",  
initialize: function() {
_.bindAll(this);
},   
startSend: function (Data) { },
reply: function (Data) { 
    var dataJson = eval(Data);              
    console.log(dataJson);
    this.idTimeout = setTimeout(this.ajaxRequest(),4000);
},
problems: function (Data) {   },
ajaxRequest: function () {
    $.ajax({
        async:true,
        type: this.requestType,  dataType: this.dataType, 
        url: this.URL,  data: this.data,
        beforeSend:this.startSend,  success: this.reply,
        timeout:4000,  error:this.problems 
    });
}
```

And clean timeouts in the view (fragment):

```
initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this); 
    this.model = new ContentCollection();
    this.model.on("add", this.contentAdded);
        this.model.on("remove", this.removeContent);    
},
contentAdded: function(content) { //run it when add a model
    if (content.view == null) {
    var template_name = 'cam';                                                      
    content.view = new ContentView({model: content,template: $.trim($("[template='"+ template_name +"'] div").html() || "Template not found!")});
    $("div.camBox").empty();                
    content.ajaxRequest();                              
    this.$el.find(".content").find("div.camBox").append(content.view.render().el);                                              
    }                   
},  
removeContent: function(content) {
    if (content.view != null) { 
        content.view.remove();              
    }
    clearTimeout(content.idTimeout);
    content.clear();  //Clear the properties of the model   
}
```

- How clean a timeout when the focus is in other window and resume it when returns?
Maybe with focus method. The next code

```
$('html').focus(function() {
    clearTimeout(content.idTimeout);
});
```

in contentAdded does not work.

Edit:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14258596/way-to-stop-the-running-of-a-javascript-web-application-when-the-focus-is-on-oth

Comment: You clear JavaScript timeouts by passing the integer ID of the timeout returned by `setTimeout()` into `clearTimeout()`. You must save the return value of `setTimeout()` to be able to clear it. In your code, I see one reference to `setTimeout()` but the ID it generates and returns is not saved.

Comment: Now, after your edit, you save timout ID into `this.idTimeout` inside the `reply()` function. This will create a property of that function (object) called idTimout. Later when you pass `content.idTimeout` to `clearTimeout`, `content` doesn't hold the ID returned by `setTimeout` because it's not your `reply` object into which you saved it.

Comment: It's all about context... You can specify a `context` parameter to `$.ajax`. That way the `this` keyword points to the object specified inside all callback functions of you AJAX call.

Comment: I think that `content.idTimeout` is in the same context of the model created. When I push other button, an event is executed in `ContentView` (I haven't included it for be shorter), the model is removed of the collection and `removeContent` is executed. "content" is in the same context. I think.

Comment: My mistake for not include more code..

Comment: One mistake in your code above is that `setTimeout` is expecting a function as its parameter, but you're passing it the result from `this.ajaxRequest()`. Change it to `setTimeout(this.ajaxRequest,4000)` (no parentheses after `this.ajaxRequest`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution could be:

Specify an array for your (multiple) timeout IDs.

```
window.timeouts = [];
```

Every time you call setTimeout:

```
timeouts.push(setTimeout(...));
```

Then, if you want to stop all timeouts:

```
for(var i in timeouts) {
  clearTimeout(timeouts[i]);
}
```

Comment: Great idea! Now, I have to solve the focus function to not overload  the client of requests.

Comment: Do you Know how resume the timeouts cleaned?

Comment: You cannot resume a timeout. Once it's cleared with `clearTimeout`, it's gone... You can create a new with `setTimeout`. Or another practice is to use `setInterval`, not clear it and use some condition in the function passed to `setInterval` to decide when to execute the code that you wouldn't when you clear your timeout.