# Way to stop the running of a Javascript web application when the focus is on other window

Tags: javascript, jquery

Are there any way to stop the running of a Javascript web application when the focus is on other window?
For example, If I have AJAX executions in a application web, It'd very efficient  stop the running in that situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with the page visibility api is, that it's not cross browser compatible. No Safari, no IE<10.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API

You could try to use the windows focus and blur events. (jQuery Example)

```
(function() {
    var isFocused = true;
    $(window).focus(function() {
        isFocused = true;
    });

    $(window).blur(function() {
        isFocused = false;
    });

    function doSomeAjax() {
        if (isFocused) {
            doSomething();
        }
    }

});
```

It's not that fancy as the page visibility api, because it only tells you, whether the tab is focused or not, but it might be enough to achieve, what you're trying to do.

Comment: `focus` indicates that the window is other?

Comment: @vicenrele I don't understand what you're asking, sorry.

Comment: Sorry. When I change the tab of the browser, isFocused would be "true"?

Comment: It should be true, when you open the tab where the script is running and should be false when another tab is focused.

Answer (score 3):

[Using the Page Visibility API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/pagevisibility/intro/)

> The Page Visibility API performs a simple but important function – it
>   lets your application know when a page is visible to the user. This
>   basic piece of information enables the creation of Web pages that
>   behave differently when they are not being viewed.

[Visibility.js](https://github.com/ai/visibility.js) - a wrapper for the Page Visibility API

Comment: A quick question (if you know Visibility.js). The AJAX execution stops and resumes automatically or not?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is too theoretical. There's no native way in JS for keeping track of window focus, but it's relatively simple to implement your own.

Once you know if the window has focus at a given point in time, you can use this information in your implementation that continuously fires AJAX requests (most likely in some kind of loop) and skip the firing of the request when window is not focused.

E.g.

```
var winFocused = false;

window.onfocus = function() {
  winFocused = true;
}
window.onblur = function() {
  winFocused = false;
}
```

Then in your "loop" or whatever, for e.g.:

```
setInterval(function() {
  if( ! winFocused) return;

  // Otherwise, if winFocused is true, do what you need...

}, 1000);
```

Comment: And, are there any way to stop the function execution? i.e. next code will not run until a flag is changed. Like `while(flag){}`but not as inappropriate

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `beforeSend` settings to store the `jqXHR` object in an array and then, on `window.blur` loop through the array and abort each request. Simplified example below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ajaxRequests = [];
    $.ajax({
        "beforeSend": function (jqXHR, settings) {
            ajaxRequests.push(jqXHR);
        },
        //... other settings
    });
    $.ajax({
        "beforeSend": function (jqXHR, settings) {
            ajaxRequests.push(jqXHR);
        },
        //... other settings
    });
    $.ajax({
        "beforeSend": function (jqXHR, settings) {
            ajaxRequests.push(jqXHR);
        },
        //... other settings
    });
    $(window).blur(function () {
        var xhr = null,
            i = 0;
        for (i = ajaxRequests.length - 1; i = 0; i -= 1) {
            xhr = ajaxRequests.pop(); //remove last jqXHR from array and return it
            xhr.abort(); //abort it
        }
    });
});
```